# Is the sentence 'I have eaten lunch since I was really young.' grammatically right?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Is the sentence grammatically right?

> I have eaten lunch since I was really young.

Can this sentence directly/indirectly mean 'I ate lunch everyday'?

Comment: *Everyday* is an adjective (*everyday clothes*); use *every day* to refer to *all days*.  You could say *I have eaten lunch every day since I was really young.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have **eaten** lunch since I was really young

Is grammatically correct, but could be understood **literally** to mean you have been eating lunch **continuously** (at one sitting) for many years, which is impossible, but people would probably understand what you mean

> I have **had** lunch since I was really young
>   I have **always had** lunch since I was really young
>   I have **eaten** lunch every day since I was really young

using **had** is what a native speaker would probably say to mean they have had lunch

Many non-natives speakers will say

> I have **taken** lunch

which seems dependent on how the phrasing is translated from their native language